# How much more hardware is needed in a cross-fed CBC rocket than a non-cross-fed one?

Tags: rockets, design, liquid-fuel

Is it just a matter of adding a multi-in fuel manifold?

Comment: Highly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31849/is-asparagus-staging-possible/31851#31851

Comment: You'd need more than that unless you're willing to have fuel pouring out of everything upon booster separation... Additionally, you'd need to pump the fuel from the side boosters to the centre core, requiring energy from somewhere. You could get this from the rocket engines' preburners/turbopumps, but that would likely require designing the engine for producing extra rotational power. You could also use electric motors to pump the fuel, but you'd need to carry a lot of battery power to move it upwards and against the acceleration of the rocket engines. Google Rocket lab's Electron rocket.